# How can I get flex items positioned within a grid element aligned to the center

Tags: css, reactjs

I am building a react App for a Pizza store and I have a bit of a problem getting my items aligned to each other with CSS.

I created a pizza section and aligned the items in a grid but in each div, I have a div that I aligned flex. The Items look okay except they all look scattered.

This is what I am aiming to achieve:

[image]

This is what I am getting: [image]

I thought it was the way I wrote my JSX code but I rewrote and tried to style it and I am still getting the same results.

My JSX code

```
<div className={styles.PizzaContainer}>
       <div>
         <img src={halfHalf} alt="half-half"/>
         <h1>Half & Half pizza</h1>
         <p>Two pizzas in one</p>
         <div>
          <h3>from ₦4,800</h3>
          <button>Create</button>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div>
          <img src={chickenCurry} alt="chickencurry"/>
          <h1>Chicken Curry</h1>
          <p>Red onions, bell peppers, chicken, pineapple, mozzarella, tomato sauce, curry, chili peppers</p>
         <div>
          <h3>from ₦3,100</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div>
         <img src={pepperoniFresh} alt="pepperonifresh"/>
          <h1>Pepperoni Fresh</h1>
         <p>Pepperoni, mozzarella, green peppers, pizza sauce</p>
         <div>
          <h3>from ₦2,700</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div>
         <img src={chickenBbq} alt="chickenbbq"/>
          <h1>Chicken BBQ</h1>
         <p>Chicken, red onions, corn, mozzarella, bbq sauce, tomato sauce</p>
         <div>
          <h3>from ₦2,700</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div>
         <img src={sharwarmaPizza} alt="sharwarma"/>
          <h1>Shawarma Pizza</h1>
         <p>Mayonnaise & ketchup, spicy chicken, red onions, tomatoes, mozzarella</p>
         <div>
          <h3>from ₦3,100</h3>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.PizzaContainer{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  column-gap: 10px;
}
.PizzaContainer div h1{
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.PizzaContainer div p{
  color: #918F8E;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  text-align: left;
}
.PizzaContainer div>div{
  margin: 20px 0 5px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 16px;
}
.PizzaContainer div>div h3{
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.PizzaContainer div>div button{
  background-color: white;
  color: #F97225;
  border: 1px solid #F97225;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be that your `p` tag has different heights. A very quick, but short-term fix would be to give your `p` tags a fixed height, but that will just cause issues down the line.

What I would do is split your Pizza "Cards" into two, grouping the image, title and description together ("PizzaCardHeader") and doing the same for the price and button ("PizzaCardFooter"):

```
<div className={styles.PizzaContainer}>
  <div className={styles.PizzaCard}>
    <div className={styles.PizzaCardHeader}>
      <img src={halfHalf} alt="half-half" />
      <h1>Half & Half pizza</h1>
      <p>Two pizzas in one</p>
    </div>
    <div className={styles.PizzaCardFooter}>
      <h3>from ₦4,800</h3>
      <button>Create</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

That way you can use flexbox to ensure they line up:

```
.PizzaContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
}

.PizzaCard {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.PizzaCardHeader {
  width: 100%;
}

.PizzaCardHeader h1 {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.PizzaCardHeader p {
  color: #918F8E;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.PizzaCardFooter {
  margin: 20px 0 5px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.PizzaCardFooter h3 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.PizzaCardFooter button {
  background-color: white;
  color: #F97225;
  border: 1px solid #F97225;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q9bc8wua/1/

Comment: Thanks vansch. I got stuck on this for almost an hour.